# Axis and Allies 1942 second edition and attacking subs

Tags: axis-and-allies

When a Sub attacks a battleship in Axis and Allies 1942 second edition. Can the battleship defend itself against the attacking sub?

Answer (score 1):

http://axisallies.com/rules/axis-allies-rules-1942-2nd-edition.pdf

From "3. General Combat"

The Battleship can defend itself during "Step 4. Defending Units Fire" as long as it is alive, or if it was moved behind the Casualty Strip in "Step 3. Attacking Units Fire".

If the Battleship is destroyed during "Step 2. Submarine Surprise Strike or Submerge", then no, it does not get to defend itself.

> Step 2. Submarine Surprise Strike or Submerge ... Once all attacking
>   and defending submarines that conducted a Surprise Strike have fired,
>   the casualties they have generated are removed from the game and this
>   step is over for this round of combat.